# How to view only the files those only included in git repo in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I am developing a new extension for OpenCart using VSCode as IDE.
The root folder is the workspace folder, and I want only to change some files.
I set the .gitignore file to ignores all files except the files I want to work on.
This is my `.gitignore` file

```
.htaccess.txt
config.php
php.ini
index.php
.vscode/*

#ignore all
*/*
```

Then I added my working files:

```
git add path/to/file.php -f
```

everything is ok.
The problem is VSCode shows every file in the workspace.

I want to view only my working files.
I tries this trick:

[image]

It is good but still not working very well, as I have to open each folder to let VSCode find those files.

Is there any way to let VSCode shows only the files included in git repo?
*VSCode highlights those files by the way.*

Or at least is there any way to hide all files except specific files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can **define** which files you want VSCode to **hide in your workspace**.

In folder `.vscode`, which folder you're *ignoring in git*, you add a file `settings.json` to define which settings you want to use at *your local workspace*. VSCode support option `files.exclude` to **exclude** these files in workspace.

This is example for your situation:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,

        ".htaccess.txt": true,
        "config.php": true,
        "php.ini": true
    }
}
```

You can see how it works in the following picture

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @huynshamha, But how I can hide all, except some files?

Comment: you can try with pattern `"[^prefix_characters]*": true`, with files or folder you want to keep.

Comment: I tried but I did not understand the behavior, I want to hide all files in all folders, except the files that starting with `waj_`, I tried: `"**/[^waj_]*": true` but it did not work correctly